# How to run "dotnet publish" without creating web.config / .exe file?

Tags: .net, .net-core, web-config, dotnet-publish

I run "dotnet publish" command on my app, and it does create a web.config file and an exe file. I am not going to run the application behind IIS server, so I assume that these files are not really required then.

I cannot figure out how to make the command not create these files.

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <WarningsAsErrors>nullable</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>


</Project>
```

The goal is to create "framework-dependent cross-platform binary." if I understood things correctly.

It looks like .exe file is always "on" for cross-platform publish from the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-framework-dependent). Perhaps the same goes for web.config

Comment: How does your project look like?

Comment: Have added to the question